# Access to light DOM when using webcomponents.js (Shadow DOM polyfill)

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom, polyfills

I'm trying to access the light DOM when using the webcomponents.js polyfill but it does not seem to work. (works fine in native Shadow DOM/Chrome)

Here is a reduced test of what I’m trying to do:

sample: http://jsbin.com/wudakapujo/1/
code: http://jsbin.com/wudakapujo/1/edit

Any hints/pointers regarding how I could access the Light DOM data when using the Shadow DOM polyfill would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that there is a 'bug'/enhancement in the polyfill, light DOM elements are removed *unless* they are used via the content tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `<content></content>` to your template, or `<content select="span"></content>` to just get the `span` tag.

> ```
> <template>
>   <h1>SHADOW DOM CONTENT</h1>
>   <content select="span"></content>
> </template>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking in

```
this.content.getDistributedNodes()
```

See 
  https://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#accessContentDOM

Comment: Note `this.content` is not defined by default. You'd have to grab the `<content>` element from the shadow dom and all `getDistributedNodes() `